# Why is HTML surrounded the all the tags of the selected type with a box and how do I stop this?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, themes

I have an extension that shows me the Opening and closing tags of the selected HTML element. Recently, however, the HTML tags of all the selected type are being surrounded by a
square box that makes this extension useless.
How do I change this? Is it the theme I am using?

Comment: If you could share the name of the extension, others could try to reproduce it

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. Yes, I did as you suggest and disabled all the extensions and worked out which one was causing the error. I hope you have a great rest of the week

Comment: Please come back and provide enough detail to answer the quesion. Provide a list of the  extensions you had installed when you asked this question and a screenshot of what you were observing. Consider writing up the answer you found as well (see [answer]).

Comment: Possible related: the `editor.selectionHighlight` setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened because you have downloaded a VS Code extension that highlights HTML tags.

To fix this go through all the extensions that are to do with HTML and JSX
and remove them one by one through process of elimination.

Once those highlights are gone then you can slowly download the extensions that were not causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out I worked it out in the end.

It was the highlight HTML tag extension and I removed it.

The main problem with this extension is it can make things a bit confusing.

So a workaround if one really wants to use a decent HTML tag highlighter would be to install HTML End Tag Labels.

Some other helpful extensions are HTML autocomplete, autoclose and auto rename.